# Defining the set of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas in Marker's Introduction to Model Theory

Tags: model-theory

I am reading through Marker's book on Model Theory and have arrived at a definition I can't unpack.

Definition 1.1.5:

The set of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas is the smallest set $\mathcal{W}$ containing the atomic $\mathcal{L}$-formulas such that

1. if $\phi$ is in $\mathcal{W}$ then $\neg \phi$ is in $\mathcal{W}$
2. if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are in $\mathcal{W}$, then $(\phi \land \psi)$ and $(\phi \lor \psi)$ are in $\mathcal{W}$
3. if $\phi \in \mathcal{W}$, then $\exists v_i~ \phi$ and $\forall v_i~ \phi$ are in $\mathcal{W}$

What is going on in bullet 3?

Comment: It is the standard definition of the first-order language: bullet 3 define how to produce formulas with quantifiers: $\forall, \exists$. See page 9: $v_i$ are the *variable symbols* of language $\mathcal L$.

Comment: Example: consider the language of arithmetic and the atomic formula $(v_1=0)$. If we call it $\phi$, then $\exists v_1 \phi$ will be: $\exists v_1(v_1=0)$.

Comment: So if I read you correctly, $\exists$ and $\forall$ really take a variable and a term (which we write next to each other) and "$\exists v_1$ such that $\phi$" is the literal unpacking of $\exists v_1~ \phi$ ?

Comment: Not a *term* but a formula. Terms are either variables or constants or "complex" terms (i.e. $x+y$). Quantifiers are applied to formulas: $(x=0), (0 < 1)$ etc.

Comment: Having said that, YES: $\exists x (x=0)$ reads: "there is an object (number) that is equal to *zero*" and more complex examples (page 7): $\forall x \exists y (x=y+y \lor x=y+y+1)$.